# Edit Order confirmation on Shopify

Tags: if-statement, notifications, shopify

I've been editing the code of the order confirmation on my Shopify store, my target is that if a customer orders a product with "this" tag and the transaction type is "Bank Transfer" then it will show "this" text. I've been trying to edit it but the code doesn't reflect on the email notification of the user. Can anyone have an Idea about this?

My Code looks like this:

```
{% assign found_pnmm = false %}
{% assign found_svmml = false %}

{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}
    {% if product.tags contains 'PNMM' and transaction.gateway == 'Bank Transfer' %}
        {% assign found_pnmm = true %}

     {% elsif product.tags contains 'SVMML' and transaction.gateway == 'Bank Transfer' %}
        {% assign found_svmml = true %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

 {% if found_pnmm %}
<p><strong>show this</strong></p>


{% elsif found_svmml %}
<p><strong>show that</strong></p>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Looks, good, is it not working?

Comment: Yes, it's not showing. I don't know what's wrong with the code. There is a text above that code tho states that "Hi {{ customer.first_name }}, we're getting your order ready to be shipped. We will notify you when it has been sent.<br><br>"

Comment: I think you need to get the `{{ line.product.tags }}` using the single line items, you can't access the product directly into the loop.

Comment: Hmmm from what I understand with what you are saying, it's not possible to create "and" statement for the {%payment.gateway%} and the {%product.tags%}?

Comment: need to use like this one `{% if line.product.tags contains 'PNMM' and transaction.gateway == 'Bank Transfer' %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon doing some tests, Shopify can't capture 2 values at the same time which are tags and payment gateway. I just did create a collection and call the spill once the product inside the collection is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably coming from these lines:

```
{% if product.tags contains 'PNMM' and transaction.gateway == 'Bank Transfer' %}
```

and

```
{% elsif product.tags contains 'SVMML' and transaction.gateway == 'Bank Transfer' %}
```

You are trying to access `product.tags`, but in the context here, `product` is going to be a property of `line` inside your for loop. So you need to be accessing `line.product.tags` rather than `product.tags`.

Comment: Thank you for that idea, but it didn't work also. For now, I'm planning to target it individualy. First is to target Just the product tag, but the code didn't seem to work also This is my code: {% if line_item.product.tag contains 'PNMM' %} do you have any idea why it's not triggered?

Comment: Is it `.tags` in the actual code? You put `.tag` in the comments here, so that might be it if that's also what is in the code. Otherwise, that ought to work. Maybe try looping through the tags and rendering each one to make sure the casing matches 'PNMM' the way you are expecting?